# How do I change the color of text wrapped only in <div> tags with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

OK, specifically, I’ve got a `div` with some text in it on my Wordpress blog and I’m trying to figure out the custom CSS to change the text color.

```
<div class=“foo-bar">
  Some text here
</div>
```

I’m sure this is some beginner mistake, but for some reason when I write

```
.foo-bar {

  color: #abc;

}
```

Nothing changes. Variations of the `color` attribute aren’t changing anything either.

NOTE: Because I’m using WP Customizer UI I can’t change the HTML

Comment: Have you tried adding `color: #abc !important;`?

Comment: Well,  #abc isn't a valid color.  Try to avoid the !important route if you can,  it will quickly become a game of css whack-a-mole.  Have you  tried a more specific selector like `div.foo-bar` ?

Comment: @gvfordo `#abc` is a valid color value.  It expands to `#aabbcc`.  Here's a link to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#numerical).

Comment: @gvfordo I’ve tried that as well

Comment: Is your CSS inline or in an external style sheet?  Are your other styles working correctly on the page?

Comment: Ah,  so it is. Well, if you can't specify a more specific style rule you'll have to go the !important route and hope there's not a more specific !important already styling it (inspect the text on the page to see the rules being applied)

Comment: @KaiChristensen where are you editing this CSS?  Is it actually being included by your page?  If not, then that would be your problem. :-)  And did you make sure about the quote?  I've seen editors do that, or had it happen when copying and pasting from another page (some sites automatically make them into "smart quotes", which causes issues with copying and pasting).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have had some sort of copy and paste error, but the quotes surrounding your class don't match.  You start with “ and finish with ".  Make them both ".

```
<div class="foo-bar">
  Some text here
</div>
```

Comment: Good eye!  Probably some editor or web page that he copied it from converted the normal quote to a fancy one.

Comment: I agree I would never have noticed that! Not what’s causing the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @KaiChristensen Yes it is with the markup you have furnished. If it doesn't fix your problem then you have other issues with markup you haven't shown.